# Show ToolTip until Mouse Leave

Tags: winforms, telerik, tooltip

I need to show a tooltip while the mouse hovers on WinForms RadGridView header cells. The tooltip's text is different based on the current cell the mouse is hovering on. I don't want the tooltip to be disappeared until the mouse leaves the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum time is about 24 days... I suppose it's enough :)
Best way is to use ToolTipTextNeeded event:

```
private void radGridView1_ToolTipTextNeeded(object sender, ToolTipTextNeededEventArgs e)
{
    // if cursor hover GridHeaderCellElement
    var header = radGridView1.ElementTree.GetElementAtPoint(PointToClient(MousePosition)) as GridHeaderCellElement;
    if (header != null)
    {
        e.ToolTip.AutoPopDelay = int.MaxValue; // 24.86 days
        e.ToolTipText = "123";
    }
}
```

or ( tnx to @checho )

```
private void radGridView1_ToolTipTextNeeded(object sender, ToolTipTextNeededEventArgs e)
{
    // if cursor hover GridHeaderCellElement
    if (sender is GridHeaderCellElement)
    {
        e.ToolTip.AutoPopDelay = int.MaxValue; // 24.86 days
        e.ToolTipText = "123";
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use the sender of the event: 
  GridHeaderCellElement headerCell = sender as GridHeaderCellElement;
            if (sender != null)
            {

            }